# OpenGl es 1.0 - Does each section of the texture need to be in powers of two?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I know that the whole sprite sheet needs to be in powers of two but when I only use a section of it, does the section also need to be in powers of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The texture coordinates are from 0 to 1 as floats.

Texture Coordinates Ex:

```
    final float texCoords[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
    };
```

To get a certain position get the 'percent'

Ex:

```
quad.SetTexCoordinates( ((float) posX / texture.Width), //X
        ((float) posY / texture.Height),                //Y
        ((float) width / texture.Width),                //Width
        ((float) height / texture.Height));             //Height 
//All are between 0 and 1 as a 'percent'
```

Comment: So the actual section being grabbed doesn't have to be in powers of two. I have a sheet at 2048x2048 and I use sections that are 512px by grabbing .25 of the sheet. but I guess as long as the sheet is in powers of two, the rest doesn't matter.